# OnRead event from scanner (Motorla EMDK) fires continuously

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008-sp1, .net-cf-3.5, motorola-emdk

(I'm using VS2008 with EMDK v2.9 with Fix1)

I have a form, where I declare my reader:

```
Private WithEvents barcodeReader As Barcode.Barcode = New Barcode.Barcode
```

I want it to be active only in one of the controls on the form, so I do this:

```
Private Sub txbAccount_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txbAccount.GotFocus
barcodeReader.EnableScanner = True
End Sub
```

And turn it off the same way in the `Lost Focus` event of that textbox.

Here is the `OnRead` sub:

```
Private Sub barcodeReader_OnRead(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal readerData as Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData) Handles barcodeReader.OnRead
If (readerData.HasReader) Then
    Try
        Dim ctrl As TextBox = Ctype(GetActiveControl(), TextBox)
        If (ctrl.Name = "txbAccount") Then
            ctrl.Text = readerData.Text
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is: as soon as I enable scanner in the `GotFocus` event of the textbox, the `OnRead` event will fire over and over (with empty data) until I actually press the scan key, scan actual data - then it stops.

I've read that maybe the `Handled` property is not getting set properly, however I don't see property like that for this.

Answer (score 0):

Quick question to answer is the `handled`is usualy within the `e` eventargs (although I dont see any in that routine just `readerdata` it may be in there!?

On a side, with barcode scanners they usualy use the sendkeys commands to simply pass string through to the system. These can be trapped easily by using any of the `OnKeyPress` / `OnKeyDown`... etc. If you wanted to go down this route, you'll need to take each keypress / down as aan individual character, whereas your barcode.OnRead might do all that for you. (Again I havent used the EMDK you reference).

Lastly 'usualy' barcode scanners end with a `cr` (carriage return) some barcode scanners can turn this off, or change these in settings. If not this might be where the `e.handled` referenced elsewhere is talking about. This would be something like ..

```
 if e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) then
      e.handled = true
 end if
```

This would stop the send going to the object (textbox) and therfore not losing focus (as the enter key wasn't passed)

Hope this helps.. a bit :)
Chicken